# How to add a discount column that varies according to a set of conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to add the discount column, it varies on the basis of account type and services. The discount column is not present in any table.

I want a column discount column at run time, while discount varies on the basis of `Resller_name`, `Account_type`, and services as well.

How can I add discount column?

Also i need to add calculated cost column with below formula:
 a.list_cost*(1-d.discount). I tried to create a table discount and added exception values and created below script:

```
select a.account, a.name, b.Resller_Name, b.bcn, 
b.Account_Type as "Internal\reseller", a.service, a.list_cost "cost of service",
d.discount, a.list_cost*(1-d.discount) as "Calculated Cost" 
from imtest.cloudchckr_test_full a, imtest.master_info_test_full b, imtest.discount d 
where a.account=b.AWS_id(+) and b.Account_type=d.account_type;
```

but it only shows a discount on the bases of account type.

[image]

Comment: I tried to create a table discount and added exception values and created below script:
select a.account,
a.name,
b.Resller_Name,
b.bcn,
b.Account_Type as "Internal\reseller",
a.service,
a.list_cost "cost of service",
d.discount,
a.list_cost*(1-d.discount) as "Calculated Cost"
from imtest.cloudchckr_test_full a,
imtest.master_info_test_full b,
imtest.discount d
where a.account=b.AWS_id(+)
and b.Account_type=d.account_type;
 

but it only shows discount on the bases of account type.

Comment: Use `join` instead, doesn't  make your life miserable :)

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using that proprietary `(+)` operator for outer joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add order is to discount table or any unique Id in discount table after that join all table and get discount amount. Do left join with discount table you will get null value if data not exists.

Comment: There is no unique value in discount table.
I have attached output of discount table

Comment: If user uses any discount coupon you will have relationships.  And user inner join can you share table structure.

Comment: try this did't understand problem but check this and use inner join if both table have same data with mandatory. select a.account, a.name, b.Resller_Name, b.bcn, 
b.Account_Type as "Internal\reseller", a.service, a.list_cost "cost of service",
d.discount, a.list_cost*(1-d.discount) as "Calculated Cost" 
from imtest.cloudchckr_test_full a
left join imtest.master_info_test_full b on a.account=b.AWS_id(+)
left join mtest.discount d on b.Account_type=d.account_type;

Comment: This query works fine with discount on account type bases.
But we have one more column which is services , based on certain services we have zero % discount irrespective of account type.

Comment: You can either use case statement or join for this what are the service do you have that don’t have discount

Comment: Please see below services which have 0% discount irrespective of account type.
Marketplace
APN Annual Program Fee
TaxTypeCanada
VAT Tax
US Sales Tax
GST Tax
Unknown
Reserved Instances Marketplace

Comment: Thanks amit for suggesting the case. It worked well :)
Please see below query , can you please help me how to calculate discount because below query is giving error. Error : Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ")" Position: 462

Comment: Which query are you talk about?

Comment: select a.account,

b.Resller_Name,

b.Account_Type as "Internal\reseller",
a.service,
a.list_cost "cost of service",
case 
when b.Resller_name='SIRIUS COMPUTER SOLUTIONS. INC' then 0.1
when a.service in ('Marketplace',
'APN Annual Program Fee',
'TaxTypeCanada',
'VAT Tax',
'GST Tax',
'Unknown',
'Reserved Instances Marketplace') then 0.0
when account_type='Reseller' then 0.07
else 0.02
end as Discount,
a.list_cost*(1-cast(Discount) as decimal(4,2)) as "Calculated Cost"
from imtest.cloudchckr_test_full a,
imtest.master_info_test_full b
where a.account=b.AWS_id(+);

Comment: Hey I don’t know if In works In case statement but you can use or condition “ a.service=‘1’ or a.service=‘2’ “

Comment: Ramkishor 
Cases solved the problem for different type of discounts.
Now only issue remaining is to calculate the calculated cost using discount. when i run below query calculated amount comes as 0. Attaching another comment,

Comment: select a.account,
b.Resller_Name,
b.bcn,
b.Account_Type as "Internal\reseller",
a.service,
a.list_cost "cost of service",
case 
when b.Resller_name='SIRIUS COMPUTER SOLUTIONS. INC' then 0.1
when a.service in ('Marketplace',
'APN Annual Program Fee'
) then 0.0
when account_type='Reseller' then 0.07
else 0.02
end as Discount,
a.list_cost*(1-Discount) as "Calculated Cost"
from imtest.cloudchckr_test_full a,
imtest.master_info_test_full b
where a.account=b.AWS_id(+);

Comment: You also have to include case statement in calculated cost you haven’t included plz check that

Comment: i don't  have data or any script to test it. so i just assuming this. add case statement  and check and let know if it's help.

Comment: Thanks for your time @amit .I used Views .
Issue is resolved :)

Comment: Welcome come can you please hit up button

Comment: Sorry it says you dont have enough reputations

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   a.account, 
   a.name, 
   b.Resller_Name, 
   b.bcn, 
   b.Account_Type as "Internal\reseller", 
   a.service, 
   a.list_cost "cost of service", 
   d.discount, 
   a.list_cost*(1-d.discount) as "Calculated Cost" 
from imtest.cloudchckr_test_full a, 
   imtest.master_info_test_full b, 
   imtest.discount d 
where 
   a.account=b.AWS_id(+) 
   and (d.account_type is null or b.Account_type=d.account_type)
   and (d.Resller_Name is null or b.Resller_Name=d.Resller_Name)
   and (d.service is null or a.service=d.service)
UNION ALL
select 
   a.account, 
   a.name, 
   b.Resller_Name, 
   b.bcn, 
   b.Account_Type as "Internal\reseller", 
   a.service, 
   a.list_cost "cost of service", 
   0, 
   a.list_cost as "Calculated Cost" 
from imtest.cloudchckr_test_full a, 
   imtest.master_info_test_full b
where 
   a.account=b.AWS_id(+) 
   and not exists 
        (SELECT 1 
             FROM imtest.discount d 
          WHERE (d.account_type is null or b.Account_type=d.account_type)
            and (d.Resller_Name is null or b.Resller_Name=d.Resller_Name)
            and (d.service is null or a.service=d.service)
         )
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel ,
but it gives zero rows. Im attaching data from discount table

Comment: getting below error : [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: UNION types character varying and numeric cannot be matched;